# Noether Normalization and Lie Algebra of derivations on a commutative algebra $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finitely-generated, derivations

In my Lie algebra course, the professor asked us to use Noether's Normalization Theorem and use it to say something about the Lie algebra of derivations over a commutative, associative algebra. Now, Noether Normalization theorem goes like this :

> Let $A$ be a commutative finitely generated algebra over a field $k$. Then there exists algebraically independent elements $z_1, \dots, z_d\in  A$ (i.e. $B=k[z_1, \dots, z_d]$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring) such that $A$ is a finitely generated module over $B$.

Now the question posed by our professor is certainly open-ended, but I ask this question because what I'm thinking seems too strong and feels like it classifies a big class of derivation algebras, which seems unlikely. So far what I have got is that, $\text{Der}(k[x_1, \dots, x_n])$ can be thought of as a free module over $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ with generators given by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. So for a finitely generated commutative algebra $A$, $\text{Der}(A)$ is the ring of derivations of $A$ which is a module over $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Intuitively I want to say that $$\text{Der}(A)\cong \text{Der}(k[x_1, \dots, x_n])\otimes_{k[x_1, \dots, x_n]} A?$$
I know this is true when the module is a localization, i.e. if $A=k[x_1, \dots, x_n][f^{-1}]$ then my claim holds. I expect it fails generally, but does the Noether Normalization theorem make life simpler in any ways at all?

Any comments and suggestions welcomed, I don't want a full solution but maybe something that might suggest I am moving in the right direction or in the wrong direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your isomorphism is very false. For example, if A is finite dimensional, then its normalization is just k, so the right hand side of the isomorphism is just zero. The left hand side is rarely zero, though. You can compute everything by hand for A = k[x]/(x^2).

Comment: (btw, Der has to be the space of *K-linear* derivations for this to have any hope; if you look at absolute derivations then you get things that come from derivations of the field itself)

Comment: One way in which normalization is useful is the following one. Denote Der(A,M) the A-module of derivations A\to M with values in an A-module M. If B is a normalization of A, then you can look at the relation between Der(B,A), which is easy to compute, and Der(A,A), which is what you want. The relation between these two things is encoded in the Zariski-Samuel exact sequence.

Comment: Not Zariski-Samuel, sorry, i think this is called the fundamental sequence for derivations or something like that.